# R improving the code with subsetting and adding two columns

Tags: r, filter, subset

I need some help to improve part of my code (I'm a beginner).
I have a big database (flussi_coord) with a column containing the name of different regions. Each region is associated with a warehouse, and I need to add two columns with its coordinates to flussi_coord; these are contained in another matrix called coord_oba. oba is just a list of the regions, created with levels(flussi_coord$oba).

The solution I came up with works, but it is terribly slow. For every row of flussi_coord, I check if there is correspondence with a name in oba; if true, I paste longitude and latitude of the warehouse in two vectors, which are later on added to the flussi_coord.

```
for (k in 1:dim(flussi_coord)[1]) {      
  for (i in 1:length(oba)) {             
    if (flussi_coord[k,5] == oba[i]) {
      LongMag[k] <- coord_oba[i,1]
      LatMag[k] <- coord_oba[i,2]
    }
  }
}
flussi_coord <- cbind(flussi_coord, LongMag, LatMag)
```

I know I need somehow to filter the database selecting the rows that match a certain region, add the two columns and iterate for other regions. I tried to look for similar solutions but I just can't get the code run.

```
#this doesn't work
for (i in 1:length(oba)) {
  flussi_coord[which(flussi_coord$OBA == oba[i]), ]$Longititudine_magazzino <- coord_oba[i,1]
  flussi_coord[which(flussi_coord$OBA == oba[i]), ]$Latitudine_magazzino <- coord_oba[i,2]
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible example, that we can easily run? For example by posting the out put of `dput(flussi_coord[1:10,])`

Comment: You should be using `merge` for this. I don't know your column names so this is incomplete, but something like `merge(flussi_coord, cbind(oba, coord_oba))`. (Where does `coord_oba` come from? Is it in the same order as `oba`?)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the datasets are data frame, this should work:

```
flussi_coord$LongMag <- coord_oba[match(flussi_coord[,5], oba),1]
flussi_coord$LatMag <- coord_oba[match(flussi_coord[,5], oba),2]
```

Comment: Hi @lelloba , Happy to be helpful :) Could you please accept the answer by clicking check mark and upvoting? Thanks.

Comment: I did it @phago29, and this is the message I get: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :)

Comment: @lelloba there is a check mark just under the down arrow. You can click on it. Thanks :)